# Execute code after node has been created

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to define a TikZ key that automatically executes some code after a node has been created.

E.g., I would like to define `stuff` such that

```
\node[stuff] (Test) {Test};
```

will execute

```
\coordinate (eastSide) at (Test.east);
```

afterwards.

Note that `execute at end node` (or its internal equivalent `\tikz@atend@node`) does not help here, because when the code given to `execute at end node` is executed, the node does not yet exist. (We get the error `Package pgf Error: No shape named eastSide is known.`)

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter  

\def\afterNodeCode{%
  \coordinate (eastSide) at (\previousNodeName.east);
}

\tikzset{%
  stuff/.code=
    \appto\tikz@atend@node{%
      \xdef\previousNodeName{\tikz@fig@name}%
      % \afterNodeCode  % does not work, too early to refer to the node
    }%
}


\node[draw,stuff] (Test) {Test};
\afterNodeCode % I would like to remove this line


\node at (eastSide) {X}; % Just for testing

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this example, I would like to remove the call to `\afterNodeCode` after the `\node` command, and I would like that the `stuff` key automatically executes the `\afterNodeCode`.

**EDIT:** `append after command` is not what I am after, either. `append after command` only evaluates paths while I need to execute arbitrary TiKZ/TeX code in `\afterNodeCode`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done via `append after command` key

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[stuff/.style={
    append after command={coordinate (#1) at (\tikzlastnode.east)}
  }
]
\node[stuff=eastSide] (Test) {Test};
\node at (eastSide) {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I think you are reinventing the wheel since this is simply a `label=0:X` for the `Test` node.

Comment: `append after command` cannot be used to execute arbitrary code. It only executes paths. For example, `append after command=\afterNodeCode` will not work in my minimal example, because `\afterNodeCode` contains a command (`\coordinate`). In this simple setting, I can of course rewrite `\afterNodeCode`, but in my full scenario, this is not possible. (`\afterNodeCode` contains, for example, calls to `\pgfpointanchor` and tests based on the result of that call).

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh Yes I know. But if you don't give your full test case I can't help further. You can always bundle your code in `\pgfextra` for arbitrary code. However, I still feel like you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to make a test case that is still simple enough, because I am actually doing quite a lot of stuff in `\afterNodeCode`. And I don't know what exactly I can drop without risking that there is a simple solution for the special case (like `label=0:X`) that does not apply to the whole. So for what it's worth, here is a full test case: https://gist.github.com/dominique-unruh/dc805ced851e849afe5028ddef0b171d The call that I want to get rid of is in line 211.

Comment: Using `append after command=\pgfextra{\afterNodeCode}` works! If you update to include that, I can accept it.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh Good that you figured your way out but there are some limitations to such use if you plan to use colors etc. but they might be edge cases. By the way, if you implement the typical gates like CNOT and Toffoli stuff I will be the first user :P

Answer (score 1):

I missed Dominik's comment so I'm writing an answer based on [Tikz: execute code after creating a node without touching the path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679565/tikz-execute-code-after-creating-a-node-without-touching-the-path)

If you don't want to insert any path, you can use `\pgfextra ... \endpgfextra`:

```
mystyle/.style={
  append after command={\pgfextra%
    any code you want%
  \endpgfextra}}
}
```

(note that using the `\endpgfextra` syntax completely disable tikz parsing strategy, so I guess it's safer than `\pgfextra{}`)