# Tikz: execute code after creating a node without touching the path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

For some reasons (in order to make a node influence the style of an arrow pointing to it in tikzcd), I need to execute a code that reads `\tikzlastnode` to get the name of the current position in a tikz(cd) matrix, but this is only defined after the creation of the node. Unfortunately, `append after command` expects a path (an empty path is not a valid input apparently), so I need to create a fake, empty node just to execute a path, and it sounds really dirty, and I'm afraid that it might cause issues (adding space, disturbing the next paths…). Can we run `append after command` (or equivalent) without disturbing the path at all?

MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \rar[/utils/exec={\message{BBBBB The message above (AAAA) should be equal to \tikzcd@ar@target}}, draw=\myfillcolor] & |[append after command={
    %%% Creating an empty node + /utils/exec sounds really dirty:
    node[/utils/exec={%
      \message{AAAA I need to have access to the name of the current node \tikzlastnode}%
      \gdef\myfillcolor{red}
    }%
    ] {}
  }
  ]| B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Someone proposed `\pgfextra ... \endpgfextra` and it works! Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \rar[/utils/exec={\message{BBBBB The message above (AAAA) should be equal to \tikzcd@ar@target}}, draw=\myfillcolor] & |[append after command={%
    \pgfextra% this syntax with \endpgfextra completely turns off the tikz syntax, that might be safer than \pgfextra{...}.
      \message{AAAA I need to have access to the name of the current node \tikzlastnode}%
      \gdef\myfillcolor{red}%
    \endpgfextra%
    }]| B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "in order to make a node influence the style of an arrow pointing to it in tikzcd" In case it's an X-Y question, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I use `append after command` with path creation within `\pgfextra` and `\pgfendextra` to work with `\tikzlastnode`. I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry great, thanks a lot, it's exactly what I needed. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ well it's exactly what I want to do ^^ I'm writing a library https://github.com/leo-colisson/zx-calculus and depending on the node you want to link to you might want to do different actions (in particular target different anchors) and doing it so manually is very error prone. But I think I have all the needed elements now.

Comment: Inside a “normal” TikZ-CD (where every node is given a name) the name of the node can be accessed inside the node's text as `\tikz@fig@name`. Though, `\tikzlastnode` might be the safest bet without havin to check yourself if an explicit name has been given.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I think to remember that I tried to use that, but the number of the figure was not the good one. I also tried to use the tikzmatrix name, but this one was again different.